# Angular 5 viewchild only works once

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

to get idea about my question here is an explanation about what is happening and what is not :

I've got upload function which uploads .zip files, get's all html code, images and converts it to strings. For every upload it repeats, after that when I load that .zip file it always extract it and converts all of it's content to string -> and I am putting it in .  The problem is that it works only once ( putting strings to iframe) .

Here is how it works :

I get zip files and call ShowVisualContent() to convert all of it's content to strings. All of the strings are in my navService -> this.html: string;

```
   this.uploads = this.db.list(`profile/${this.auth.userId}/projects/${this.projectId}`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
      return actions.map((a) => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
        this.navSrv.showVisualContent(data.url, data.name);
        const $key = a.payload.key;
        const $ref = a.payload.ref;
        return { $key, ...data, $ref };
      });
    });
```

Then in my component i get that html:string;

```
 @ViewChild('html') html: ElementRef;
 loadHtml(){

    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.html.nativeElement.src = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(this.navSrv.html);
    },4000);
    console.log("Loading html into iframe now")
  }
```

And load it in html like this :

```
<div  *ngFor="let upload of uploads | async">
  <iframe style="min-width:1300px;min-height:800px;" id="framex" #html scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
 </div>
```

The main problem is that when I have lot's of zip files loaded in one page, I get only 1  with converted html strings in it.

**How to make that this.html would be in all  not only in one.**

How to get value as an array from each function call :

```
html: string;
      this.html = xmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

(this is the part where I put all html in this.html string, and it get's only the last value.)

How to get all html's as an array ?

this is the function where I get innerHTML of all .zip files :

```js
html:string;


public showVisualContent(contentUrl:string, fileName:string) {
    console.log(contentUrl);
    console.log(fileName);
    let fileInfo = getFileInfo(fileName);
    if(fileInfo) {
      switch(fileInfo.type) {
        case 'archive' : {
          getAllFileContentsFromRemoteZip(contentUrl, (files) => {
            //TODO: Remove timeouts. This is just a temporary option for demonstration purposes.
            //Also this is a massive function that must be separated into multiple functions
            setTimeout(() => {
              let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
              for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].fileInfo.type == 'image') {
                  // Create a storage reference from our app
                  // Create a reference with an initial file path and name
                  let imageRef = storageRef.child(files[i].fileInfo.fileName);
                  files[i].url = imageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                    return url;
                  });
                }
              }

              setTimeout(() => {
                for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                  //console.log(files[i].fileInfo.fileName);
                  //console.log(files[i].url);
                  if(files[i].fileInfo.type == 'web') {
                    let parser = new DOMParser();
                    let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(files[i].content, "text/html");
                    //scripts
                    let scriptElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('script');
                    for(let j = 0; j < scriptElements.length; j++) {
                      let attr = scriptElements[j].getAttribute('src');
                      if(attr) {
                        for(let k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
                          if(attr.includes(files[k].fileInfo.fileName)) {
                            scriptElements[j].removeAttribute('src');
                            scriptElements[j].innerHTML = files[k].content;
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    //styles
                    let linkElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('link');
                    for(let j = 0; j < linkElements.length; j++) {
                      if(linkElements[j].getAttribute('rel') == 'stylesheet')
                      {
                        let attr = linkElements[j].getAttribute('href');
                        if(attr) {
                          for(let k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
                            if(attr.includes(files[k].fileInfo.fileName)) {
                              //do stuff
                              let parentElement = linkElements[k].parentElement;
                              if(parentElement) {
                                let styleElement = parentElement.appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement('style'))
                                styleElement.innerHTML = files[k].content;
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }

                    //images
                    let imgElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('img');
                    for(let j = 0; j < imgElements.length; j++) {
                      let attr = imgElements[j].getAttribute('src');
                      if(attr) {
                        for(let k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
                          if(attr.includes(files[k].fileInfo.fileName)) {
                            //do stuff
                            //imgElements[k].setAttribute('src', 'data:image/' + files[k].fileInfo.ext + ';base64,' + files[k].content);
                            imgElements[k].setAttribute('src', files[k].url.i);
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    //console.log(xmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML);
                    this.html = xmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
                    for(let j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
                      if(files[j].fileInfo.type == 'image') {
                        let strings = getStringsToReplace(files[j].fileInfo.fileName, this.html);
                        for(let k = 0; k < strings.length; k++) {
                          this.html = this.html.replace(strings[k], files[j].url.i);
                          this.html = this.html.replace('/' + strings[k], files[j].url.i);
                        }
                      }
                    }
                   // console.log(this.html);
                  }
                }
              }, 500);
            }, 1000);
          });
        }
        case 'web' : {
          //show simple html here. Unlikely to happen
        }
        case 'image' : {
          //show image here
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ViewChild by design get's you one instance, use viewChildren :

```
@ViewChildren('html') htmls: QueryList<ElementRef>;
loadHtml(){

  setTimeout(()=> {
    this.htmls.map((elem) => {
       elem.nativeElement.src = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(this.navSrv.html);
    }
  },4000);
  console.log("Loading html into iframe now")
}
```

for a better understanding of ViewChild & ViewChildren, queryList checkout this article https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

Comment: Yes it worked but now I got another problem, when I get .zip files from storage and convert it's content to html:string and now showing it, it shows only the same one html.

Comment: You should just change the way you handle 'this.navSrv' so it can work with an array, as things stand now, when you map on your actions, you keep overriding this.navSrv, so it has only the last value.

Comment: Can you please watch at my edit I will put in one minute, maby you will help me with that ?

Comment: I show how I save my every innerhtml into one html string;

Comment: can you provide a full snippet of your code, i can't seem to find the declaration of xmlDoc, so i don't really understand your logic here!

Comment: it's a big one but I will.

Comment: if I console.log this.html in this function , i get all html's , but with viewchildren I get the last one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170415/discussion-between-andrius-la-and-tjadli).